# Add getSku magento class

Tags: magento

i have a class to get the product_id and name, and i want also to get the sku.

Below is my class, my question is, how can i get the sku ?, the $row->getSku() is not working.

```
class Magestore_Productcontact_Block_Adminhtml_Productcontact_Renderer_Productname extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

        return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            $this->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('_current'=>true, 'id'=>$row->getProductId())),
            $row->getProductName(),
            $row->getSku()
        );
    }
}
```

this is on phtml file to result the name and href.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('_current'=>true, 'id' => $row->getProductId())); ?>"><?php echo $row->getProductName() . $row->getSku(); ?></a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It will be necessary to know what class `$row` is and if it's an instance of `Varien_Object`, what its properties are.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s %s</a>',
     $this->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array('_current'=>true, 'id'=>$row->getProductId())),
     $row->getProductName(),
     $row->getSku()
);
```